# Which AdWords ad is performing better: Low CTR but Low CPC or High CTR but High CPC

Tags: google-ads, advertising

I have 2 ads in my ad group. A and B

```
A : 75% Serviced, CTR is 14% but CPC cost is : 6.215 VND
B : 25% Serviced, CTR is 8% but CPC cost is : 5.969 VND
```

Which ad should be stopped or updated?
[image]

Comment: not enough info. which campaing gives you better relation in terms customer/cost? those campaign should run further, another one should be stopped.